How do I loosen this nut of my toilet lid?
I want to change my toilet lid. On the underside of the toilet bowl, the lid is fixed with a nut and a rectangular item (see image). How do I open this nut? It does not move. How did the craftsman even tighten the nut? There seems to be not enough space to rotate the rectangular item.


General FYI... square nuts in the modern age are usually not intended to be manipulated. They're almost always a sign that your concern is at the other side.

I believe you mean toilet seat, not toilet lid.

@Martha: Usually both are joined together as one unit?

There should be a cover on the top of the toilet that hides the screw head, the other end... Those screw heads will be where you turn, the item you pictured holds the nut from turning, so you only need to loosen it from the top

Yep, that long bracket is only there to keep the square nut from rotating when you turn the top side of the bolt.

@Huesmann - to be fair, the bracket (and nut) does rotate a bit as seen from the trail of black rubbed-off metal on the porcelain.

@JonCuster well, yes, as the bracket tightens, it rubs against the porcelain.  Until it's clocked by the bowl.  The point is for it to be long enough that rotating will eventually stop against something.
